# How to get RGB byte array for the mouse cursor in win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi, direct3d

I use the following code to get mouse cursor bitmap:

```
HCURSOR hCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(NULL, IDC_ARROW, IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

ICONINFO info = { 0 };
BOOL ret = GetIconInfo(hCursor, &info);
```

When I save the `info.hbmMask` bitmap to a file, it looks like this:

[image: Mouse cursor bitmap]

I want to use this cursor as a Direct3d9 texture for drawing. I do not know how to convert this monochrome bitmap into an RGB byte buffer which can be used for creating the texture.

Or is there any other way to get an RGB byte array of a standard Windows cursor?

Comment: Use `GetDIBits` to extract the bits from a bitmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An icon consists of **two** bitmaps working together, as described in the [`ICONINFO` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648052.aspx):

> hbmMask
>   Type: HBITMAP
>
> The icon bitmask bitmap. If this structure defines a black and white icon, this bitmask is formatted so that the upper half is the icon AND bitmask and the lower half is the icon XOR bitmask. Under this condition, the height should be an even multiple of two. If this structure defines a color icon, this mask only defines the AND bitmask of the icon.
>
> hbmColor
>   Type: HBITMAP
>
> A handle to the icon color bitmap. This member can be optional if this structure defines a black and white icon. The AND bitmask of hbmMask is applied with the SRCAND flag to the destination; subsequently, the color bitmap is applied (using XOR) to the destination by using the SRCINVERT flag.

In your case, you have a monochrome icon, so `hbmColor` is NULL and `hbmMask` contains both the mask and the colors.  The top half is `AND`'ed with the target to clear pixels and create an empty space for the icon, and then the bottom half is `XOR`ed with the target to fill in the space created by the mask.

For a non-monochrome icon, `hbmMask` would be `AND`'ed as-is with the target, and then `hbmColor` would be `XOR`ed as-is with the target.

As Raymond Chen stated in his comment, you can "*use [`GetDIBits()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879.aspx) to extract the bits from a bitmap*".  So you have to extract the pixel bits from the appropriate `HBITMAP` and process them according to whether you are working with a monochrome icon or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use `GetDIBits()` to get the byte array of the cursor data. Do so by calling `GetDIBits()` twice, once to get the actual details of the cursor images and another time to get the pixels.

You can apply this code for the color and mask, just be aware that it only returns 32x32px cursors, even if the size is configured for something else.

After that, you can marge both.

```
var windowDeviceContext = User32.GetWindowDC(IntPtr.Zero);

//Initialize the bitmap header and calculate its size.
var maskHeader = new BitmapInfoHeader();
maskHeader.Size = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(maskHeader);

//Gets the image details.
Gdi32.GetDIBits(windowDeviceContext, iconInfo.Mask, 0, 0, null, ref maskHeader, DibColorModes.RgbColors);

//If there's any data, get it.
if (maskHeader.Height != 0)
{
    //To prevent the cursor image from being inverted.
    maskHeader.Height *= -1;

    var maskBuffer = new byte[maskHeader.SizeImage];

    Gdi32.GetDIBits(windowDeviceContext, iconInfo.Mask, 0, (uint) maskHeader.Height, maskBuffer, ref maskHeader, DibColorModes.RgbColors);
}
```

It's C#, but easily converted to your language of choice.